# Determine tagName from constructor

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to get the [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) from the constructor as if it was static? Is there a good reason those to not be statically accessible?

```
HTMLDivElement.tagName; // undefined; expected: DIV
HTMLAnchorElement.tagName; // undefined; expected: A
```

I generated a map but feels hacky and the question remains.

```
let mapping = {
  HTMLAnchorElement: "A",
  HTMLElement: "ABBR", 
  HTMLElement: "ADDRESS", 
  HTMLAreaElement: "AREA", 
  HTMLElement: "ARTICLE", 
  HTMLElement: "ASIDE", 
  HTMLAudioElement: "AUDIO", 
  HTMLElement: "B", 
  HTMLBaseElement: "BASE", 
  HTMLElement: "BDI", 
  HTMLElement: "BDO", 
  HTMLQuoteElement: "BLOCKQUOTE", 
  HTMLBodyElement: "BODY", 
  HTMLBRElement: "BR", 
  HTMLButtonElement: "BUTTON", 
  HTMLCanvasElement: "CANVAS", 
  HTMLTableCaptionElement: "CAPTION", 
  HTMLElement: "CITE", 
  HTMLElement: "CODE", 
  HTMLTableColElement: "COL", 
  HTMLTableColElement: "COLGROUP", 
  HTMLDataElement: "DATA", 
  HTMLDataListElement: "DATALIST", 
  HTMLElement: "DD", 
  HTMLModElement: "DEL", 
  HTMLDetailsElement: "DETAILS", 
  HTMLElement: "DFN", 
  HTMLUnknownElement: "DIALOG", 
  HTMLDivElement: "DIV", 
  HTMLDListElement: "DL", 
  HTMLElement: "DT", 
  HTMLElement: "EM", 
  HTMLEmbedElement: "EMBED", 
  HTMLFieldSetElement: "FIELDSET", 
  HTMLElement: "FIGCAPTION", 
  HTMLElement: "FIGURE", 
  HTMLElement: "FOOTER", 
  HTMLFormElement: "FORM", 
  HTMLHeadingElement: "H1", 
  HTMLHeadingElement: "H2", 
  HTMLHeadingElement: "H3", 
  HTMLHeadingElement: "H4", 
  HTMLHeadingElement: "H5", 
  HTMLHeadingElement: "H6", 
  HTMLHeadElement: "HEAD", 
  HTMLElement: "HEADER", 
  HTMLElement: "HGROUP", 
  HTMLHRElement: "HR", 
  HTMLHtmlElement: "HTML", 
  HTMLElement: "I", 
  HTMLIFrameElement: "IFRAME", 
  HTMLImageElement: "IMG", 
  HTMLInputElement: "INPUT", 
  HTMLModElement: "INS", 
  HTMLElement: "KBD", 
  HTMLUnknownElement: "KEYGEN", 
  HTMLLabelElement: "LABEL", 
  HTMLLegendElement: "LEGEND", 
  HTMLLIElement: "LI", 
  HTMLLinkElement: "LINK", 
  HTMLElement: "MAIN", 
  HTMLMapElement: "MAP", 
  HTMLElement: "MARK", 
  HTMLUnknownElement: "MATH", 
  HTMLMenuElement: "MENU", 
  HTMLMenuItemElement: "MENUITEM", 
  HTMLMetaElement: "META", 
  HTMLMeterElement: "METER", 
  HTMLElement: "NAV", 
  HTMLElement: "NOSCRIPT", 
  HTMLObjectElement: "OBJECT", 
  HTMLOListElement: "OL", 
  HTMLOptGroupElement: "OPTGROUP", 
  HTMLOptionElement: "OPTION", 
  HTMLOutputElement: "OUTPUT", 
  HTMLParagraphElement: "P", 
  HTMLParamElement: "PARAM", 
  HTMLPictureElement: "PICTURE", 
  HTMLPreElement: "PRE", 
  HTMLProgressElement: "PROGRESS", 
  HTMLQuoteElement: "Q", 
  HTMLElement: "RB", 
  HTMLElement: "RP", 
  HTMLElement: "RT", 
  HTMLElement: "RTC", 
  HTMLElement: "RUBY", 
  HTMLElement: "S", 
  HTMLElement: "SAMP", 
  HTMLScriptElement: "SCRIPT", 
  HTMLElement: "SECTION", 
  HTMLSelectElement: "SELECT", 
  HTMLSlotElement: "SLOT", 
  HTMLElement: "SMALL", 
  HTMLSourceElement: "SOURCE", 
  HTMLSpanElement: "SPAN", 
  HTMLElement: "STRONG", 
  HTMLStyleElement: "STYLE", 
  HTMLElement: "SUB", 
  HTMLElement: "SUMMARY", 
  HTMLElement: "SUP", 
  SVGSVGElement: "svg", 
  HTMLTableElement: "TABLE", 
  HTMLTableSectionElement: "TBODY", 
  HTMLTableCellElement: "TD", 
  HTMLTemplateElement: "TEMPLATE", 
  HTMLTextAreaElement: "TEXTAREA", 
  HTMLTableSectionElement: "TFOOT", 
  HTMLTableCellElement: "TH", 
  HTMLTableSectionElement: "THEAD", 
  HTMLTimeElement: "TIME", 
  HTMLTitleElement: "TITLE", 
  HTMLTableRowElement: "TR", 
  HTMLTrackElement: "TRACK", 
  HTMLElement: "U", 
  HTMLUListElement: "UL", 
  HTMLElement: "VAR", 
  HTMLVideoElement: "VIDEO", 
  HTMLElement: "WBR"
}
```

Comment: I looked around but didn't see anything. Such a mapping may not exist, though I'd love to be proven wrong

Comment: Probably because they inherit from HTMLElement and  Element and without an instance would be no need to explicitly define a value

Comment: @charlietfl well for some reason [defining custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) requires a constructor and a tag name, so I have a need for that :D

Comment: Ok...but custom element instances return a tagName also https://jsfiddle.net/wqr0tds2/ so not really clear what higher level problem is you need to solve

Comment: @charlietfl what you've shown is what is called an "autonomous" element, try to extend an existing one, like `HTMLDivElement`, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Given your list, there is no unique mapping and many elements use the same constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a good reason those to not be statically accessible?

Yes, because as you can see from your mapping many "constructors" are actually used for multiple different tags. `HTMLElement` being the obvious prime example, but also `HTMLHeadingElement`, `HTMLTableSectionElement` or `HTMLModElement`. In general I wouldn't even expect this mapping to be stable, if a proposal introduces new methods specific for one element kind they might get a new "class".